# Post matching query does not exist/ why is my db empty

Tags: python, django

I know where the error is occuring, but don't know why and how to fix this. I mean, I know what the error means but don't know why my code is causing that. Here's my code

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'


     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 

            self.object.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(PostCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            post = self.model.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))  
            options = {'size': (64, 64), 'crop': True} 
            context['post_thumbnail'] = get_thumbnailer(post.image).get_thumbnail(options).url
            return context


     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Error is occurring from this line

```
                post = self.model.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
```

which I don't understand because I'm getting post from one of the Post. and I'm simply getting the image of that post.

Comment: if you print `kwargs.get('pk')` and it is what you expect and the error still there, then your db doesnot contain that object. and I have no idea why your db is empty ;)

Comment: @doniyor heyhey do you mind if we chat live

Comment: @doniyor i'm still having problem over the same issue, I'm trying easy-thumbnail

Comment: sure, but I never used easy-thumbnail.. and we should first solve this bug, I think

Comment: @doniyor, but you have experience with imagekit?

Comment: @doniyor still want to fix the one couldn't solve last time

Comment: nope, never worked with imagekit. was that about ImageSpecField? I dont remember

Comment: can you help me with using thumbnail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99654/discussion-between-haloyoba-and-doniyor).